# Dealing with incoming posted (non-UTF-8 encoded ) data in a rails action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding

Given a rails 3.2 app running on Ruby 1.9:

I've got incoming data (posted from an external service over which I have no control) which comes in a post with paramaters encoded with ISO-8859-1 with no encoding specified in the content-type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

This could be interpreted to be valid according to [HTTP1.1 specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7.1) but is out of my control (and certainly it would be 100% valid if they specified the encoding in the content-type)

However it seems like [rails 3 automatically assumes UTF-8](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/25215d7285db10e2c04d903f251b791342e4dd6a). And so any non-ascii chars are giving me errors. Is there any good way to fix this? (Other than just hacking in a check and a reconversion within the action?)

PS: in case it helps, here's a test fragment that calls the error:

```
  post "incoming", {'content'=>"some content with a pound-sterling sign encoded like this: \xA3 "}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my pro-tem answer (given that in my case I always know the source is going to 8859-1 encode the text and I have only one important parameter):

```
params['content'].force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode!
```

However this could be done for all the params (to one level deep)

```
def params_to_iso_8859_1 
  params.each_value{|v| v.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode! if v.respond_to(:force_encoding)}
end
```

and this could then be a filter.

It's a bit more involved if you've got nested params, or if you want to look at the encoding given in the post's request params.